# Dent near bottom bracket on vintage steel frame

Tags: frames, repair

I just bought myself an old vintage Koga Miyata and just realized today that there's a weird dent on the frame near bottom bracket.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is this something I should be worried about? Or is it normal with these kind of frames, and what's it for?

**EDIT** judging from other pics of the same frameset it seems like it's normal? https://www.velosaloon.com/products/koga-miyata-gents-touring-frame-in-58-5-cm-c-t-57-cm-c-c-with-high-tensile-1024-tubing

Any idea what they are for and why aren't they symmetrical?

Comment: That's normal for a frame of that vintage.

Comment: Theres some large rubber in there - do you have sufficient frame clearance for that wide rear tyre?  I'd pull it and check for witness marks on the paint.  Yes, rubber can wear off steel.

Comment: @Criggie I second that. Once I had to ride home (~5km) with a buckled rear wheel. The tire sawed through about a mm of aluminum. Basically no friction loss was felt.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The chainstay has been crimped (at the time of manufacture) to provide extra clearance for the chain rings. On some bikes, I’ve seen this clearance provided by having the bottom-bracket end of the chainstay be a solid plate (thinner than the chainstay tube).

The bike almost certainly came with a multi-gear crankset when new.

Comment: The crank on the photos _is_ multi-gear.

Comment: Ah yes, it’s missing the small chainring. To make it clear: The frame is manufactured this way intentionally. When done properly crimping can actually improve strength by work-hardening the steel.

Comment: There probably should be an emphasis that this is **intentional** and **deliberately manufactured**. There is no evidence that it was damage or an after-market modification.